# Cannot drop disconnected oracle user

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to drop a user from an Oracle DB (version 12c), but can not get it to work. The error I am getting is:

```
ORA-01940: cannot drop a user that is currently connected
```

Naturally I looked around, and found out how to forcibly disconnect and kill a session. So I used the query:

```
select s.sid, s.serial#, status, s.username 
from v$session s 
where username = 'user_i_want_to_drop';
```

and then killed the only active session by using

```
alter system kill session '<sid>,<serial#>' IMMEDIATE;
```

naturally using the values from the query.

When I run the query again, it comes up empty, as expected. However, I still cannot drop the user and get the same error message.

I have noticed that when I query on `gv$session`, two sessions for that user show up. However, I cannot kill those using the `alter system kill session` statement I used above.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other session(s) are connected to another instance of your cluster.

Add `inst_id` to your `gv$session` query, like this:

```
select sid,serial#,inst_id 
from gv$session 
where username = 'user_i_want_to_drop';
```

Then, include the `inst_id` in the `alter system kill session` command, like this:

```
alter system kill session '<sid>,<serial#>,@<inst_id>' immediate;
```

E.g.,

```
alter system kill session '15,1891,@1' immediate;
```